# F# code does not work after class instantiation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#

I'm trying to translate the [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite) example to F#. Primarily I created the F# version of classes `BloggingContext`, `Blog` and `Post` as follows:

```
namespace ConsoleApp.SQLite.FSharp

open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
open System.Collections.Generic

type Post() =
    member val PostId = 0 with get,set
    member val Title = "" with get,set
    member val Content = "" with get,set
    member val BlogId = 0 with get,set
    member val Blog = Blog() with get,set

and Blog() =
    member val BlogId = 0 with get,set
    member val Url = "" with get,set
    member val Posts = [Post()] with get,set

type BloggingContext() =
    inherit DbContext()

    member val Blogs : DbSet<Blog> = null with get,set
    member val Posts : DbSet<Post> = null with get,set

    override this.OnConfiguring optionsBuilder =
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blogging.db") |> ignore
```

And, after that, I tried to create the f# version of the `Main` class, which I wrote as follows:

```
open System
open ConsoleApp.SQLite.FSharp

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let db = new BloggingContext() in
    let blog = Blog() in
    printfn "%s" "Stopped working before here";
    blog.Url <- "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet";
    db.Blogs.Add(blog) |> ignore;
    let count : int = db.SaveChanges() in
    printfn "%i records saved to database" count;
    printfn "All blogs in database:"
    for blog in db.Blogs do
        printfn "- %s" blog.Url
    0
```

As it is marked in the code, It simply stops printing anything (as well as stop working) after this line of code `let blog = Blog() in` and I don't know what I'm doing wrong to create a `Blog` instance.

Comment: What's the c# tag for?

Comment: The original example is written in C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite)

Comment: It looks like you have a recursive pattern since Blog() initializes Posts with a Post(), which in turn initializes a new Blog().

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by removing `Post()` in the line

`member val Posts = [Post()] with get,set`

being then

`member val Posts = [] with get,set`

The problem was redundancy in class declarations, and I was creating a list with one member already, which it is not what I wanted.